# Latex paint to magnet non-toxic adhesive

Tags: adhesive

I'm looking for a non-toxic adhesive for a baby's room that would glue a relatively lightweight magnetic strip to painted wood.

I'm fixing some blackout window blinds that use a magnet to attach a side rail that blocks some light. The magnet originally came with some 2-sided tape adhesive on it  but it has since lost its adhesion. (*I think due to the cold weather*)

I would normally just use a construction adhesive but I'm worried about fumes, etc.

Comment: Perhaps a stronger double sided tape, no fumes.

Comment: If the magnet strip doe not cost much, replace with new one is my recommendation. Also, can it be nailed down (with pre-drilled holes), which will hold it in position in a positive manner.

Comment: Most adhesives don't emit fumes of any type once they've reached their full cure state (check the packaging to find out how long that takes - most likely 24 hours or less). Once cured, they're probably no more or less toxic than the things they're holding together. i.e., if you're kid is licking the adhesive, he's also licking the paint, the magnet itself, the tape that held the magnet in place, the tape residue, etc., yet you're not worried about the toxicity of those. Keep the kid away from the glue while it's curing and don't worry about it once it's cured.

Answer (score 0):

Automotive trim mounting tape: this is very strong double sided tape, I hope you're not renting.